# Warum heißt es »Ruderin«, nicht »Rudererin«?

Tags: noun, gender

Aus den Verben *rudern* und *lehren* ergeben sich Tätigkeitsbezeichnungen:
Ein Mann ist *Ruderer* oder *Lehrer*.
Eine Frau ist *Ruderin* oder *Lehrerin*.

Naiv erwarte ich, dass die weibliche Form *Rudererin* heißt.

Wie kommt es, dass die weibliche Form unterschiedlich gebildet wird?
Hat die Endsilbe *-er* verschiedene Bedeutungen? Liegen den Worten verschiedene Regeln zugrunde?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Das Substantiv *Ruderer* ist eine männliche Personenbezeichnung, die aus dem Verbstamm *ruder* (vom Verb *rudern*) und der Endung *-er* gebildet wird. Weibliche Bezeichnungen werden mit dem Suffix *-in* zur männlichen Form gebildet.

Da das Doppel-er in der Mitte eines Wortes jedoch schwer auszusprechen ist, wird es zu einem *er* zusammengefasst. Das ist im Deutschen die Regel, wie folgende andere Beispiele belegen:

- der Zauberer – die Zauberin
- der Wanderer - die Wanderin
- der Förderer - die Förderin

Die Tilgung des zweiten *-er* erfolgt also [sprachökonomischen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprach%C3%B6konomie) Gründen.

Comment: Es könnte auch mit der Betonung zusammenhängen. Die mit "-erer" endenden männlichen Personenbezeichnungen werden auf der Silbe vor der Endung betont, "Lehrer, Hörer, Kehrer, Fahrer, Pfarrer" usw. auf der Silbe vor dem "-rer" (einmal davon abgesehen, dass diese Worte alle nicht auf "-erer" enden). Auch der Wortklang scheint eine Rolle zu spielen. Das Verb *nörgeln* wird substantiviert zu *Nörgler / Nörglerin* oder *Nörgeler / Nörgelerin* - und nicht *Nörgelin*. D.h. trotz gleicher Betonung wird "-erer" anders behandelt als "-eler".